# Having trouble with if statements and raw_input in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the code

```
Members = ["MrRager", "Giancarlo", "TheFoolishOne"] # participants of Last Man Standing Challenge
MrRager = raw_input("Did Mr Rager make it through today?")
if MrRager == raw_input("No"):
        Members.remove("MrRager")

print Members



 # every time a member fails, doesn't check in for a while, or leaves we will remove from list above.
```

So, basically I want the script to ask the question did the member make it through today. If the raw_input is a yes it will stay the same. Then, I want if I type a no, it will remove the person from the list. Put when I type no it prints it again and then keeps the list the same.

Comment: `MrRager == raw_input("No"):` ??? => `MrRager == "No":`

Comment: You write `raw_input(..)` in **your `if` statement, so the program will query again...

Comment: On the sidenote, why am I seeing a lot of C#-styled Python code lately? :D Camelcase and stuff...

Comment: @bosnjak Camelcase definitely sucks.

Comment: I don't even know what Camelcase means. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` takes the user's input and returns it so it's stored in the `MrRager` variable. You don't need to take the user's input again, just test the contents of that variable:

```
if MrRager == "No":
    Members.remove("MrRager")
```